# Why .geocodeAddressString doesn't change external variable?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I have an external variable chooseCoordinates, which has a type of CLLocationCoordinate2D. This var need to save coordinates from geocodeAddressString closure, but, apparently, it doesn't change.

I would like to ask for advice, how to make this actually closure store the data, so I will be able to parse it to another viewController

```
var chooseCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
////////////

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(sender.text!, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if(error != nil) {
            print("\(error)")
        }

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
            self.chooseCoordinates = coordinates
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geocodeAddressString` runs asynchronously (i.e. even though the method returns immediately, its `completionHandler` closure may be called later). So, are you sure it's not changing, or just not changing by the time you try to use `chooseCoordinates`? You should initiate whatever updating of the UI or whatever from within the closure (or the `didSet` of `chooseCoordinates`), not doing so immediately. We don't see how you're using `chooseCoordinates`, so it's hard to be more specific than that.

For example:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(sender.text!) { placemarks, error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    }

    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
        let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
        self.chooseCoordinates = coordinates
        // call the method that uses `chooseCoordinates` here
    }
}

// don't try to use `chooseCoordinates` here, as it hasn't been set yet.
```

Or, you might employ the `completionHandler` pattern yourself:

```
@IBAction func didEndEditingTextField(sender: UITextField) {
    geocodeAddressString(sender.text!) { coordinate, error in
        self.chooseCoordinates = coordinate
        // trigger whatever the next step is here, or in the `didSet` of `chooseCoordinates`
    }

    // don't try to use `chooseCooordinates` here
}

var chooseCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?  // you probably should make this optional

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

/// Geocode string
///
/// - parameter string: The string to geocode.
/// - parameter completionHandler: The closure that is called asynchronously (i.e. later) when the geocoding is done.

func geocodeAddressString(string: String, completionHandler: (CLLocationCoordinate2D?, NSError?) -> ()) {
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(string) { placemarks, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            completionHandler(placemark.location!.coordinate, error)
        } else {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the first one in my another view controller and it worked, so it really was about synchronisation.